# si daré uso a las APIS de google maps, que tipo de cuenta google requiere y es necesario tambien google cloud

Tags: gmail, cloud

si daré uso a las APIS de google maps, que tipo de cuenta google necesito y es necesario tambien google cloud

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que dice la documentacion de google al respecto?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.